# How to count Attributes from an Entity in Core Data with Swift and iOS 9?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios9

I am stuck with `Core Data` on counting the amount of item in a particular entity item.

Here´s how it is going:

I have 2 entities: `Categories` and `Subcategories`. The relationship is *To-Many* from `Categories` to `Subcategories`.

On each of them I have the `name` *attribute*.

So what I need is to get the *amount of* `Subcategories` I have by `name` and store that amount on an *attribute* I will create on `Categories` under the `subcategoriesAmount` *attribute*.

The main view is a `tableview` with `Categories` I can add and also have on each *cell* a *label* that will display the *amount of subcategories*, and clicking on each cell, after a category is added, with load another `tableview` with the `Subcategories` that I can add or were already added. So as I keep adding *subcategories* and later on get back to the `Categories` table, I wan to display the *amount of subcategories* corresponding to the category it is connected.

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your relationships are setup correctly, you should just be able to access the subcategories of your category directly. For example: `category.subcategories.count`.

If you wish to store that as an attribute keep in mind that you'll need to update this value every time you add or remove a subcategory. It sounds a bit like a premature optimisation to me.